# specifying source IP-address for socket.connect() in python sockets

Tags: python, sockets, server, client, tcp

how do we set the source IP-address when we do `__socket.connect((host, port))` on a machine that have a several ethernet interfaces?

Comment: Explain a bit more the question. Using `connect(('179.XX.XX.XX', 5005))` is enough for setting the connection

Answer (score 9):

Before you use `connect()`, use

```
socket.bind((ipaddr, port))
```

to determine the source addr and source port. If addr or port is equal to '' or 0, it means using OS default.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the host IP like @Jalo said `connect(('179.XX.XX.XX', 5005))`, the system will choose wich interface needs to use to interact with that host.

If you need more info to understand how just read [Routing in Linux](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/04/route-examples)

Comment: I interpret the question as being specifically about overriding the default routing. How to open a socket using the default routing is not a very relevant answer.